# securely transmit password with HTTPS and cookies

Tags: php, cookies, ssl, authentication, https

I am rather new to PHP, so please bear with me. I have created a web site which I have protected with basic authentication and SSL (Apache server). However, this scenario is anything but secure since userid and password are transmitted as plain text. I have considered digest auth, but that doesn't quite fly for unrelated reasons.

Hence I am now considering SSL-encrypting the entire site (which is already the case), and using a cookie-based mechanism for session authentication. I have read and (I believe) understood the basics of how to set and unset cookies with PHP, but I cannot find a good example of how to implement the mechanism for a secure login. Yet this must be an extremely common login scenario, hence I would think that some pre-fabricated login pages may already be available for easy customization.

I would be exceedingly grateful if somebody could direct me to a step-by-step tutorial of how to implement a cookie-based secure login! many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SSL for the entire site, then the username and password are not transmitted in plain text but as part of an encrypted connection.

Basic authentication in combination with SSL is a sufficiently safe setup for most web apps.

Comment: Codo, thank you for your rapid and correct response. However, I should have mentioned would like to make certain parts of the site conditionally accessible to specific users. But maybe I can accomplish that by defining several virtual servers in Apache - or is this better done with a cookie mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion of terms here. First, you are incorrect in stating that sending passwords via SSL is insecure. Second, you are confusing authentication with authorization. Authentication proves that the user is who he says he is. The username and password do that, so that part is finished. At that point you create a session for the user, containing his identities and the roles he may assume. The session is preserved across requests via a cookie. Then when he accesses certain parts of the site you must check his roles to see if they match the roles you have defined as being required to accesses that area. You can do all that part of it via Apache configuration without having to write any code at all.

Comment: Thank you. I will do my reading and hopefully achieve what I have in mind!